# Instagram graph API unable to upload video using single or carousel

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

1. upload media using api  ""https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/90010177253934/media?image_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsol...&is_carousel_item=true&access_token=EAAOc..."
   "

[upload media using api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEPf0.png)

2. create container using api "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/90010177253934/media?caption=Fruit%20candies&media_type=CAROUSEL&children=17899506308402767%2C18193870522147812%2C17853844403701904&access_token=EAAOc..."

[create container using api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRSpo.png)

3. Publish carousel container using api "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/90010177253934/media_publish?creation_id=18000748627392977&access_token=EAAOc..."

[Publish carousel container using api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrpRF.png)

I've tried all above step mention in the documentation but getting error as show in pics
Here is official document link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm a bit confused that you appear to be sending only GET parameters with your POST requests there. Not sure the API accepts their use interchangeably in all places.

Comment: If you see their official document they are doing same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution Instagram has change media_type pram it not exception video furthered, instead of vide pass reel

e.g media_type: reel